# How to disable botton if ImageView appear?

Tags: android, button, if-statement

I have a problem with the disable button.

my code

```
public class try1 extends Activity {
private String[] myString1;
private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources();

    myString1 = res.getStringArray(R.array.primary);


    final Button btn1;
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String q = myString1[rgenerator.nextInt(myString1.length)];
            ((Button) v).setText(q);

            if( findViewById(R.id.button5).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)

            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press Next to Go", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             

                    }
        }
    });
    final Button btn2;
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String q = myString1[rgenerator.nextInt(myString1.length)];
            ((Button) v).setText(q);

            if( findViewById(R.id.button5).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)

            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press Next to Go", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             

                    }
        }
    });
    final Button btn3;
    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String q = myString1[rgenerator.nextInt(myString1.length)];
            ((Button) v).setText(q);

            if( findViewById(R.id.button5).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)

            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press Next to Go", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             

                    }
        }
    });
    final Button check;
    check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String q = myString1[rgenerator.nextInt(myString1.length)];
            ((Button) v).setText(q);

            if (btn1.getText().equals(" ")||(btn2.getText().equals(" ")||(btn3.getText().equals(" "))))
            {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "choose answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            

                        }
            else if (btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString1[1])||(btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString1[2])||
                    (btn2.getText().toString().equals(myString1[0])||(btn2.getText().toString().equals(myString1[2])||
                            (btn3.getText().toString().equals(myString1[0])||(btn3.getText().toString().equals(myString1[1])
                                    ))))))
                                    {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "wrong answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             

                                    }

                            else if (btn1.getText() == btn2.getText()|| (btn1.getText() == btn3.getText()||
                                    (btn2.getText() == btn3.getText())))
                                    {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "something same", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();           

                        }
                            else if(btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString1[0]) &&
                                    (btn2.getText().toString().equals(myString1[1]) &&
                                            (btn3.getText().toString().equals(myString1[2]) )))
                            {
                                findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }



        }
    });

    Button next;
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent("com.learn.lone"));

        }
    });

}
```

}

I have some `button1, button2, button3` that if at the clicks appear random text,

and I have a check button, this button serves to check the answer right or wrong on the button above. if the correct answer will display `ImageView`

I have a problem if `ImageView` appear, then I can not click button1, button2.button3. I can only press the **Next** to continue.

what should I add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes u can as your condition satisfied than in that if loop use something like this

```
button1.setEnabled(false);
button2.setEnabled(false);
button3.setEnabled(false);
```